# Filter array of objects, update object value and then replace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have some data that looks something like this:

```
const somedata = {
    abc: [
        {number: 1, letter: "a"},
        {number: 2, letter: "b"},
        {number: 3, letter: "c"},
        {number: 4, letter: "d"},
    ]
}
```

I filter out the object that I want like so:

```
const currentItem = somedata.abc.filter((item) => item.number === 1);
```

Which returns this:

```
[{number: 1, letter: "a"}]
```

At this point - I'd like to update a value - Something like this, but I'm not sure this is the best way?

```
currentItem[0].number = 100
```

Which returns this:

```
[{number: 100, letter: "a"}]
```

I'd then like to replace that object in `somedata.abc` - This is where I'm getting stuck.  Any help would be really great!!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Heads-up: it's already updated in the original array because the object you are altering is the same one in the original array. BTW [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is better fitted for this job than [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) unless there are multiple objects with the same number that you want to alter also.

Comment: Does that mean without using filter you want to update the object directly.

Answer (score 1):

try it by yourself !
As each element of the array are objects, they are treated by reference and any changes will be made directly on it

```js
const somedata = 
      { abc: 
        [ { number: 1, letter: 'a' } 
        , { number: 2, letter: 'b' } 
        , { number: 3, letter: 'c' } 
        , { number: 4, letter: 'd' } 
      ] }

somedata.abc.filter(x=>x.number===1)[0].number = 100

somedata.abc.forEach(el=>console.log( JSON.stringify(el)) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ... also if you gonna use `filter` like that at least use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead like so: `somedata.abc.find(x => x.number===1).number = 100;`. `find` will return `null` if no item is found, so you should also check that out before attempting to set the `number`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir you are right, but I preferred to respect the PO code, so as not to disturb him too much, because the bottom of his question just concerns the principle of referencing objects

Answer (score 0):

You can also create program like this to match your workflow exactly

```js
const somedata = {
    abc: [
        {number: 1, letter: "a"},
        {number: 2, letter: "b"},
        {number: 3, letter: "c"},
        {number: 4, letter: "d"},
    ]
}

// Find item ID function
const getCurrentItemId = f => { for(let i = 0; i < somedata.abc.length; i++) if(somedata.abc[i].number === f) return i };

// Find ID by searching number key
const currentItemID = getCurrentItemId(1);

// Get copy of item data
const currentItem = { ...somedata.abc[currentItemID] };

// Now you do some logic with
// your currentItem data and 
// then update local value
currentItem.number = 100;

// Then if you want to put updated
// value back to original array...
somedata.abc[currentItemID] = currentItem;

// Log new object's array
console.log(somedata);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const somedata = {
abc: [
    {number: 1, letter: "a"},
    {number: 2, letter: "b"},
    {number: 3, letter: "c"},
    {number: 4, letter: "d"},
]
}

//filter array based on your needs
var arr = somedata['abc'].filter(function(el){
return el.number ==1
});

//update array
arr.map(function(o){
if (o.number == 1){
    somedata['abc'].find(item =>item.number == 1).number = 100;
};
});

console.log(somedata);

/*
 {
 abc: [
  { number: 100, letter: 'a' },
  { number: 2, letter: 'b' },
  { number: 3, letter: 'c' },
  { number: 4, letter: 'd' }
  ]
}
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it would be using map():

something like below should do the job for you

```
somedata.abc = somedata.abc.map((item) => {
  if (item.number === 1) {
    item.number = 100;
  }

  return item;
});
```

Details about it here => https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

Comment: that's a job for `forEach` not `map`

Comment: What makes you say that ? making a statement without explanation isn't good enough...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant `forEach` is better here because the original array and the mapped array are the same (contain exactly the same objects), `map` should be used only if the contents of the array are changed in some way. BTW, I didn't downvote you

Answer (score -1):

```js
const somedata = {
abc: [
    {number: 1, letter: "a"},
    {number: 2, letter: "b"},
    {number: 3, letter: "c"},
    {number: 4, letter: "d"},
]
}

somedata.abc.filter(item => item.number===1).forEach(item => item.number = 100)

console.log(somedata)
```

Comment: Don't use `map` if you don't want to create a new array